# Spam Defeating All My Captcha

Tags: php, wordpress, captcha, recaptcha, spam

I have a wordpress blog and I had the Captcha plugin on it for the longest time because it worked. Lately though I am getting mass amounts of spam. I then tried to do a "Add These Random Numbers Together" that were generated via PHP but still no luck. I'm not quite sure what I need to do to block this spam but it is quite annoying.

I was reading about some kind of visual script that spammers use - that reads your webpage or something thats why Captcha has the messy images to block this sort of thing. I was thinking that maybe it would help if I put a animated GIF background behind my PHP Random Number Captcha so it would be easy for a use to read but hard for a bot.

Not sure anyway I need suggestions :S

Comment: If your captcha is being bypassed automatically, then no amount of animated backgrounds is going to help it. Check that the captcha is actually working, or you haven't left open some OTHER method of spamming your blog which completely bypasses the captcha.

Comment: I had a problem like this on my BlogEngine.net website... for me, the problem was that even though the ReCaptcha was displayed, it could be ignored and was unnecessary. I eventually just switched to Disqus though.

Comment: Since I do not know for certain I won't put this as an answer. Computer Vision is a field of study all on it's own. Eventually engineers will be able to defeat any Captcha. If your's is easily defeated I would first suspect that somehow they are able to get around the Captcha. Something silly like you do the check in the Javascript before submitting and they are able to make the check always return true. Stackoverflow seems to get around this problem, if you might want to ask a question about how they do it.

Comment: @all heh, seems like we all had the same train of thought. :) choo choo..

Comment: Assuming these are spam comments, I'd recommend adding [Akismet](http://akismet.com/) to any solution you look into; It was developed by Automattic specifically to defeat WordPress spam, and is free for personal use. Certainly works well for me.

Comment: Whelp, I'm kinda trusting on the plugin to do the right work - I'm not putting in the captcha manually it just kind of... plugs it in. And it does work, if I enter the wrong captcha it stops me, if i dont enter the captcha it stops me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using [reCAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/learnmore)? It has plugins that are easy to use ([PHP](http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/php.html) for example).

Comment: Actually even though everybody has great explinations and suggestions I went with this option. This way I'm not trusting some random Wordpress Captcha plugin I'm putting my trust in google to keep spam out. We'll see how this works. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

As in many other areas of antisocial behavior, the comment spammers are constantly improving their game. Captcha was really effective, until the spammers actually improved the state of the art in OCR. Then there are the "are you a human?" types of tests -- adding numbers, identifying pictures, etc -- and those can be defeated by ... humans, very inexpensive humans.

This means that, just like email spam, you need to up your game and start looking at *where* the comment/post is originating from. If you have a site targeting the US, the UK, or some other large, well-defined geographic area, it is possible to check the IP address and use that as part of your "spam or ham?" calculation. Additionally, you can look at the *contents* of the comment and see if it seems to be full of links, or is composed almost entirely of just one link.

Limiting posts to registered users helps, as does making sure that all first comments are handled by a moderator.

We use a scoring method that uses IP-block include and exclude lists, link count (checking both HTML and simple text patterns), and a minimum comment size. Comments that fall into a grey area are kicked to a moderator. This is a US-oriented Django site, so I can't point to a PHP class or WP plugin, but this combination has substantially reduced the flood. At least for the moment it has.

Comment: Right, we have all the comments check by a moderator but it's almost like overnight we get somewhere around 20 or 30 spam comments that I have to go though and delete. The IPs all are completely different so it has to be a bot - I almost with it was just one person so I could nip it in the bud but this doesnt seem to be the case. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of public CAPTCHA-scripts that you can use, Google's "reCAPTCHA" being one of them, others want the user to tell whats on a photo or other riddles ...

The problem is: You can never block human spammers. Sometimes it's not a bot that's solving your CAPTCHA but a real person. There's even a business for solving CAPTCHAs where people are paid to solve CAPTCHAs and provide bots with solutions.

One solution that I found is working pretty well: make it hard (if not impossible) for spammers to use the account they created. Spammers only have that much time so when they need too much of it to actually post to your blog, they'll go away eventually.
Meaning: let only people post that you approved personally, let only people post links that have posted at least X (meaningful) posts before.
I don't know about wordpress, but this worked for me in phpBB, I'm sure there are similar plugins for wordpress.

Comment: I guess this is a possibility but its stupid comments like "[]...My Blogs Title...[]" that just seems useless for a human spammer to do. The only sort of "spam" is the link to a website it provides when adding the comments (its an optional field)

Comment: Right, that's why I suggested to keep people from posting links (whether it's in the comment itself or in the website-field) before you have approved them.